# Should I use get or got?

Tags: present-subjunctive

> My sister and I vowed to study English hard when we got back to the U.S. (this family is traveling across the world)

At first glance, I thought the vowing process in that
sentence occurred after they came back to the U.S, but it turned out that promise was made when they were traveling.

At this point, I began to wonder. If that’s the case, shouldn’t “get” be used instead of “got”? My friend argues “got” should be used since the sentence is past tense, but idk it just seems awkward to me.
If so, how would you write a sentence that actually means they made the vow after they came back to U.S.?

I just don’t get how that sentence means they vowed to study English while they were traveling since it just seems like he and his sister vowed after they were done traveling.

Comment: I would have thought that _get_ was appropriate if they are still travelling. "We vowed that we will study hard when we get back."

Comment: 1: *He said he'd eat when he **gets** home* implies ***he hasn't got home yet*** (i.e. - that "when" refers to some ***future*** time) But the "backshifted" version 2: *He said he'd eat when he **got** home* implies nothing at all about whether he's home yet or not. That second version could be talking about something he said yesterday or last year, OR ten seconds ago.

Comment: ...Maybe "implies nothing at all" is overstating the case above. But to the extent that #2 *slightly* implies "he had already got home by the time of reporting what he said", this is only because the speaker ***didn't*** use phrasing #1 (which is always completely unambiguous).

Comment: 'My sister and I have vowed to study English hard when we get back to the US'  sounds more natural to my ears, the 'have' harmonising with the 'still travelling, but vowed during this period' aspects.

Comment: It's an attachment ambiguity, and the past tense matches either interpretation. The present tense is appropriate only in a direct quote.

Comment: vowed with an ed past morpheme triggers got with an o.

Comment: The sentence is ambiguous. The naturally inferred meaning is that they promised each other while they were on holiday that they'd study when they got back. It could also mean, "When we got back to the U.S., we vowed to study English hard."

Answer (score 1):

to get back [to a place] is an idiom.
Past tense: got back

We **vowed** to study English when we **got** back.

Otherwise, it would be:

- We **vow** to study English when we **get** back. [present tense]

Another example:

I promised to do better when I leave. [buzzer]
I promise to do better when I leave. [okay]
I promised to do better when I left. [okay]

The actions or vowing and promising have to agree with the when clause or it simply does not make semantic sense, not to mention grammatical sense.

And it has nothing to do when the sentences are uttered in terms of when they are traveling. It has to do what they want to say.

Comment: The things described by the clauses "we vowed..." and "when we got back" do not have to take place at the same time and therefore don't have to agree in time. "I promised my mom on her birthday in 2020 that we'd go to Bermuda once the pandemic was over." The two events are separated by more than a year, but perfectly correct grammatically.

Comment: @speedfranklin That sentence is completely different but I can point this out: it is in the simple past and would go is the past tense of will go. So, the sentence is fine and is not relevant here at all.

Comment: "Will go" is a future construction of "to go" whose simple past tense is "went". "Would go" is a compound construction (nothing simple about it!). I disagree that the example about when a promise is made and when the action occurs (like my example) is irrelevant to the OP's question. Maybe if I flip it around it will seem more appropriate: "When the pandemic is over, I promised my mom on her birthday that we would go to Bermuda."

Comment: @speedfranklin I repeat: there is no subjunctive in the question at all.